# GET request is firing twice with Window scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm fetching some ajax when a Window scroll event evaluates to true. In the network tab, I noticed the GET request is firing twice on succession for each event, even though I have set a timeout flag to disable the ajax function running many times (currently 3 seconds).

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

**Edit:** One thing I've just noticed is that on document ready, it fires twice, so it might not even be scroll related.

[image: get request firing twice]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Infinite Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var offset = 0;
    var limit = 10;
    // jsonplaceholder is an working example endpoint.
    var apiEndpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_offset=";
    var working = false;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        getContent();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log("Fired if ==", $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(), getDocHeight());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
            if (working == false) {
                working = true;
                getContent();
                //console.log("Fired! Offest = ", offset);
            }
        }
    });

    function getContent() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: apiEndpoint+offset+"&_limit="+limit,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: '',
            success: function(res) {
                //console.log(res);
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    // replace title and body with properties you need to extract from res
                    $('body').append("<div><h1>"+res[i].title+"</h1><p>Content: "+res[i].body+"</p></div>");
                }
                // no need to run timeout on first use (page load)
                if(offset !== 0){
                    // stop ajax call firing too rapidly 
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        working = false;
                    }, 3000)
                }
                offset += 5;
            },
            error: function(res) {
                console.log("Something went wrong! - ", res);
            }
        });
    }

    // Get document height (cross-browser compatibility)
    function getDocHeight() {
        var D = document;
        return Math.max(
            D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
            D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
            D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
        );
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use jQuery 3.3.1?  There are a few ajax updates that might help the cause.  I would start there, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated to 3.3.1. No difference.

Comment: Probably a "preflight" since you're not in the same origin as your ajax call. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why sending a POST by AJAX is interpreted by the HTTP Server as OPTIONS and sending by CURL is effectively a PUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191955/why-sending-a-post-by-ajax-is-interpreted-by-the-http-server-as-options-and-send)

Comment: It's tough to understand that, but I think you are right. I also noticed I can't reproduce the behaviour on IE11.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey - voted to close with same dupe you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

salam, your get request is the second one, in the first request the method type is "OPTIONS" represents a request for information about the communication

for more details [DOC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: salam , if you get your data from your web site use a relative path , within you needn't a connection request